# A binary operator with incompatible types was detected error in Azure Search with Helix

Tags: helix, azure-search

I'm getting the below error after deploying on Azure. We're using Azure Search with Helix pattern reusing Habitat's Foundation.Indexing style (indexing providers).

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":"Invalid expression: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Boolean' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'And'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"}}
```

What does this error mean? Search was working fine on Azure staging but not on production instance.

Comment: Can you provide some more information please? Are prod and staging using the same index? If they are using different indexes have they both been rebuilt? It looks like an issue with one of your predicates. I would try to isolate the issue by removing predicates and conditions to your query to figure out which field is causing problems. But check the indexes first.